# What URL does this route match?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

```
“routes.MapRoute("static",
    "welcome",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "index" });”
```

So does it mean go to `Home/Index?` What is "welcome" in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is the name of the route, second is the url and the third part is the default values.

Please refer to the official documentation next time, for instance this tutorial:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs

This specific route would apply only for url: {root}/welcome , where {root} may be something like www.mysite.com and it will use controller with name Home and activate its action Index.